# "error: cannot find symbol" regarding on Inheritance-related program

Tags: java, inheritance, netbeans-8

I got a message says `error: cannot find symbol` regarding on `c1.certificateAwarded(grade);` statement. I have no idea what is the problem. Really need all the help I can get.

Here's the code:

**ExamDetails.java**

```
package Exams;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ExamDetails {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        StudentResults sr = new StudentResults();
        sr.inputStudentName();
        sr.inputExamName();
        sr.inputScore();
        sr.inputGrade();
        sr.DisplayDetails();

        Certificates c1 = new Certificates();
        c1.certificateAwarded(grade);
    }

}
```

**StudentResults.java**

```
package Exams;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class StudentResults {

    private String fullname;
    private String examName;
    private int examScore;
    private int examGrade;

    public String getStudentName()
    {
        return fullname;
    }

    public void setStudentName(String name)
    {
        fullname = name;
    }

    public String getExamName()
    {
        return examName;
    }

    public void setExamName(String exam)
    {
        examName = exam;
    }

    public int getExamScore()
    {
        return examScore;
    }

    public void setExamScore(int score)
    {
        examScore = score;
    }

    public int getExamGrade()
    {
        return examGrade;
    }

    public void setExamGrade(int grade)
    {
        examGrade = grade;
    }

    public void inputStudentName()
    {
        fullname  = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the student's name");
    }

    public void inputExamName()
    {
        examName  = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the subject's name");
    }

    public void inputScore()
    {
        String scoreString = new String();
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the student's score");
        examScore = Integer.parseInt(scoreString);
    }

    public void inputGrade()
    {
        String gradeString = new String();
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the student's grade");
        examGrade = Integer.parseInt(gradeString);
    }

    public String DisplayDetails()
    {
        String d;
        d = "Student Name : " + fullname + "Exam Name : " + examName + "Score : " + examScore + "Grade : " + examGrade;
        return d;
    }
}
```

**Certificates.java**

```
package Exams;

public class Certificates extends StudentResults {

    private String certificate;
    public String Grade;

    Certificates()
    {
        super();
        certificate = "No Certificate Awarded";
    }

    String certificateAwarded(/*int grade*/) {

        //StudentResults g = new StudentResults();
        //Grade = g.inputGrade();
        //Grade = inputGrade(examGrade);

        if(Grade.equals("Grade : A"))
        {
            this.certificate = "Certificate of Excellence";
        }
        else
            if(Grade.equals("Grade : B"))
            {
                this.certificate = "Certificate of Achievement";
            }
            else
                if(Grade.equals("Grade : C"))
                {
                    this.certificate = "Certificate of Achievement";
                }
                else
                    this.certificate = "No Certificate Awardedt";

           return this.certificate;
    }  
}
```

Comment: Where is `grade` declared?

Comment: `grade` is not declared.

Comment: What is the full error message?

Comment: Hi @ PaulBoddington, @Kami and @iamnotmaynard. I just removed the `grade` but now program stops after input(from string to int) has been entered. At the statement "inputScore". Why is that so? Thanks for the replies guys.

Answer (score 0):

In the ExamDetails.java class, you don't declare or instantiate the `grade` variable that you're passing to the `certificateAwarded` method.

Also, you have parameters commented out in your Certificates.java class. You should uncomment the parameter.

Comment: I just removed the `grade`. But something else bothers me, the program stops after input(from string to int) has been entered. At the statement "inputScore". Why is that so? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @JwanRadzi Because you'e not assigning the value pulled in from the `JOptionPane` to anything. See this site http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html You're parsing a blank `string` to an `Integer`

Answer (score 0):

For your code to compile, `grade` would have to be either

1. a local variable declared within the main method
2. a field defined on the ExamDetails class

Neither of these declarations are present so the compiler is telling you that it can't find the grade "symbol".

Try adding `int grade = sr.getExamGrade();` above the problem line, or something similar.

Comment: As 9Deuce mentions, your code as posted will produce other compiler errors once you fix this one, even when the line suggested in this answer is added.

Comment: I tried the statement but still got error so I just removed the `grade`. But something else bothers me, the program stops after input(from string to int) has been entered. At the statement "inputScore". Why is that so? Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

As the comment suggested, you need to have "grade" declared. Without it, the compiler can't complete determining what the signature is for Certficates.certificateAwarded, since what goes in the argument list is part of the signature. More importantly, you have this in your code:

> String certificateAwarded(/* int grade */)

The parameter, "int grade" is commented out.  So the compiler sees this:

> String certificateAwarded( )

So, what the compiler might be telling you is that it is looking for a method of Certificates named certificateAwarded that takes 1 argument of type {whatever type "grade" is}. It doesn't find that.

I said "might be" because you are missing two symbols on the line in question: grade and a method with a matching signature.

I can think of two things you can try to fix it:

1. Change " c1.certificateAwarded(grade);" to  "c1.certificateAwarded();"
2. Declare "grade" to be an int somewhere in main (or in a place that is visible within main) **and** change "String certificateAwarded(/*int grade*/)" to "String certificateAwarded(int grade)".

I would start by trying the first option. If it is necessary to try the second, you will need to add additional code in both main (or place where grade is visible to main) and in the certificateAwarded method.

Comment: Note that "Grade" is a different variable than "grade".  Java is case sensitive.

Comment: I just removed the `grade`. But something else bothers me, the program stops after input(from string to int) has been entered. At the statement "inputScore". Why is that so? Thanks for the reply.